# How to find application folder on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, directory

I'm going to make an app which influence another app. The only thing I don't know is ...
How to find the folder of the other app (Like "0A007EC0-F477-4A61-8F67-C075024F8463").

Does someone know it ?

Thanks,
Vinzgore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't access the file structure of another app under iOS unless its a jail broken device.  Its all sandboxed.

Comment: But if I've a JBken device, how can I do it ?

Comment: I'm sure they'll all be in a applications folder of some sort, you should be able to check the cydia dev docs for that.

Comment: Yes they are in /private/var/stash/Applications.XXXXX/ . But I can't find what app is in what folder...

Comment: If you can find the plist file in each one you might be able to tell from that.  It would mean opening a bunch of plists though.

Comment: Finally, I'll not make this app since it's a cheating app ;) but ... Thanks for your help, it was very useful !

Answer (score 1):

You can get your current applications folder using

```
NSString *pathOfApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

Hope this helps